# In Google Closure how can I get a property from a DOM element?

Tags: google-closure

I can set elements with setProperties, but there does not seem to be a getProperties to get an attribute value. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to return the attribute value use raw javascript method [getAttribute(att_name)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute).

Or if you get an attribute node by name from the current element use [getAttributeNode(att_name)](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_getattributenode.asp)

```
var elem = goog.dom.getElement(element);
var attr = elem.getAttribute('name');
var attrNode = elem.getAttributeNode('name');
```

Comment: The only exception to this is if you're using `data-*` attributes. Then you want to use `goog.dom.dataset` namespace so that you're ready for browsers that support HTML5.