# jQuery's .data in google closure?

Tags: google-closure

I want to store data associated with an element, similar to jQuery's .data, except for in Google closure.

What is the best way to do this:

```
$('#id').data('example', 'text');
```

Comment: Google closure is a compiler - it is orthogonal to how your actual business logic is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dataset - http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/local_closure_goog_dom_dataset.js.html

> goog.dom.dataset.set(element, key, value) Sets a custom data attribute
>   on an element. The key should be in camelCase format (e.g "keyName"
>   for the "data-key-name" attribute).

```
<div id="container" data-action="test"></div>

var container = goog.dom.getElement('container');
var hasDataActionAttribute = goog.dom.dataset.has(container, 'action');
var dataActionAttribute = goog.dom.dataset.get(container, 'action');
// hasDataActionAttribute true
// dataActionAttribute test
```

see also [In Google Closure how can I get a property from a DOM element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592626/in-google-closure-how-can-i-get-a-property-from-a-dom-element)

http://www.closurecheatsheet.com/dom#dataset